# O(s) nome(s) da letra "G" não depende na região?

Tags: pronúncia, nomes, diferenças-regionais

O [Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa de 1990](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?acordo&version=1990) diz que a letra "G" pode ser chamado "gê" ou "guê".

Penso que diferenças deste tipo têm tendencia variar de acordo com a região do falador. Mas tudo que posso encontrar sobre o nome desta letra é que ambos os nomes são aceitaveis.

Existe ou não variação entre "gê" e "guê" que depende na região?

Comment: Pelo menos no Brasil, várias letras podem ter nome diferente dependendo da região. Sei que no nordeste do Brasil dizem "fê" para F, "lê" para L, "guê" para G, entre outras. Tem até uma música do Luiz Gonzaga sobre isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Yd12zwNVBw

Comment: @DanGetz Pra ver como estou fraco no portugues, eu me confundi :) Obrigado.

Comment: Mas queres saber o nome da letra só? Eu aprendi como "guê" mas popularmente diz-se "gê". Em Portugal tem-se muito a *mania* de confundir "g" com "j" por causa do "gê".

Comment: Acho que varia mais de pessoa para pessoa, independentemente da região.

Comment: @Dan Estive a estudar a evolução do G, e daí resultou um resposta quase totalmente nova. A anterior tinha até erros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estou convencido que a variação regional na preferência entre os nomes ***gê*** e ***guê*** é consequência e não causa da existência dos dois nomes. A causa parece-me ser esta: nós recebemos os dois nomes do latim; e por outro lado existe uma preferência largamente maioritária pelo nome ***gê***, mas ***guê*** é o nome preferido para ensinar as crianças a ler.

No latim clássico, falado nos séculos I e II, o ***g*** tinha apenas o som /g/ (como em ***g***ato ou ***g***uerra). Portanto *genus* era pronunciado *guénus*. Depois deste período, o som do ***g*** quando seguido de ***e, i*** ou ***y*** começou a sofrer uma palatização que acabou por o transformar no /dƷ/ (como em *bri**dg**e* no inglês) do latim medieval e eclesiástico, do italiano e do romeno, no /Ʒ/ do português (*vi**gí**lia*) e francês, e no /x/ do castelhano (*Carta**g**ena*). Quando seguido de ***a, o*** ou ***u*** o som de ***g*** permaneceu /g/. [(Vejam este artigo da Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_G)

Esta mudança foi ditada pela lei do menor esforço. Para lermos ***gue***rra ou ***gui***ta, a língua coloca-se numa posição recuada para produzir o /g/ e depois tem que se chegar rapidamente à frente para pronunciar o ***e*** ou ***i***. Para pronunciarmos o ***a, o*** ou ***u***, a língua fica em posição recuada tal como para o som /g/. Portanto no latim tardio, nos conjuntos ***ge, gi*** e ***gy***, a língua foi tentando pronunciar o ***g*** em posição cada vez mais avançada para facilitar a transição para a posição do ***e, i*** ou ***y***, alterando o som da consoante. Exatamente a mesma coisa se passou com a letra ***c***, que no latim clássico representava apenas o som /k/ (Cícero era pronunciado Kikero), e depois, antes de ***e*** ou ***i***, evoluiu para /s/, /tʃ/ ou /Ɵ/ nos descendentes moderno do latim. [(As duas pronúncias podem ser ouvidas aqui.)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_Latin_Language/Pronunciation)

Ora os nomes das letras no latim clássico seguiam mais ou menos o padrão que ainda hoje seguem no português. As primeiras consoantes do alfabeto [eram pronunciadas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oWWOJW3948) (escrevendo à portuguesa) *bé, ké, dé, éf, gué*. Portanto o nome da letra ***g*** terá sofrido a palatização do ***g*** antes de ***e*** e ***i***, dando o nome ***gê*** em português e francês. ***Gê*** é por isso provavelmente o nome original do ***g*** em português. É esta a opinião deste [artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/letra-g/10621). Se por acaso os romanos tivessem lido as letras *bá, ká, gá*, a letra ***g*** provavelmente seria ainda lida *gá* nas línguas modernas.

Pelo menos desde o Renascimento que os estudiosos redescobriram o latim clássico, como se pode ver [neste artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/outra-vez-o-nome-da-letra-g/18535):

> Duarte Nunes de Leão, insigne jurista, historiógrafo e glotólogo, na sua Ortografia da Língua Portuguesa (1576), refere que usamos o G na sua própria significação quando o juntamos às vogais **a, o** e **u**, e que «outra pronunciação lhe viemos a dar, imprópria e adulterina, quando se ajunta ao **e, i**, que fica soando como **i** consoante* (...). A qual pronunciação com **e, i**, é alheia dos Gregos e Latinos, e própria dos Mouros, de quem a recebemos. De maneira que para pronunciarmos o G com **e, i**, da maneira própria e natural, como o pronunciamos com **a, o, u**, lhe acrescentamos um **u**, líquido, e dizemos Ga, Gue, Gui, Go, Gu». (* o **i** consoante é o atual **J**.)

O insigne Duarte Nunes de Leão estava redondamente enganado acerca de termos recebido a pronunciação **gê** dos mouros, mas mostra que a pelo menos a partir do século XVI já se sabia da pronúncia do ***g*** no latim clássico, abrindo a possibilidade para o nome alternativo ***guê***.

O nome ***gê*** é no entanto claramente o preferido, pelo menos na atualidade. Aqui em Portugal, creio que só mesmo as crianças nos primeiros anos de escola, e os seus professores, é que usam o nome ***guê***. Nas siglas o ***g*** é sempre pronunciado ***gê*** mesmo quando abrevia uma palavra onde é pronunciado ***guê***: por exemplo GNR, Guarda Nacional Republicana, é pronunciado *gê-ene-erre*; do mesmo modo, TGV, *Train à Grande Vitesse*, é *tê-gê-vê*. A música [A B C do Sertão](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Yd12zwNVBw) de Luíz Gonzaga, agradecimentos ao Bfavaretto pela sugestão, sugere que o nome ***gê*** é uma peculiaridade sertaneja:

> Lá no meu sertão, p'r' os caboclo ler, tem que aprender um outro ABC.

Mas há uma coisa que ajuda o nome ***guê*** a persistir: é este o nome geralmente usado para ensinar as crianças a ler: vejam [este artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/gue-ou-ge/14723) e [este outro](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/nome-da-letra-gg/13705). Eu googlei [ensino do alfabeto na educação infantil – imagens](https://www.google.pt/search?q=ensino%20do%20alfabeto%20na%20educa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20infantil&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCIQsARqFQoTCJqsoL7l_ccCFYIEGgodxkoO3A), e verifiquei que a letra ***g*** é sistematicamente ilustrada com um gato. Este [site usa uma ficha com várias ilustrações](http://alfabatezicao.blogspot.pt/2012/03/alfabeto-para-completar-atividades-para.html) para cada letra, e no ***g***, para além do inevitável gato, aparece uma galinha, um garfo, e outras coisas que começam com o som ***guê***. Parece que as crianças começam por aprender palavras com *ga, go, gu* e só mais tarde é que aprendem coisas como *gelo* e *giz*. E facilita-lhes a aprendizagem aprenderem que a letra se chama ***guê***.

É claro que o ***c*** também começa por ser ensinado em palavras em que soa ***quê*** [(vejam exemplo no último link)](http://alfabatezicao.blogspot.pt/2012/03/alfabeto-para-completar-atividades-para.html), e nem por isso mantém o nome ***quê*** entre os adultos. Creio que isso seria impedido pela existência do ***q***. O ***g*** não tem essa concorrência, porque o ***j*** se chama ***jota***. Mas eu lembro-me de aprender o *c de cão* e o *q de nove* (assim chamado devido à sua forma). Noutras paragens chamam-lhe o *q de quá-quá* (vejam comentário abaixo).

Portanto parece-me que o nome ***gê*** é o original, tendo resultado da evolução do latim tardio e depois deste para o português, com evoluções paralelas para outras línguas. O nome ***guê*** sobrevive por ser usado no ensino das crianças, recebendo também a legitimação do latim clássico.

Comment: Jacinto vê se a minha edição está correta. E já agora "q de nove" ?!

Comment: E mais uma vez uma excelente resposta com uma pesquisa fantástica.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela edição e elogio. Quanto ao _quê de nove_, já toda a gente sabe que vivemos em Portugais diferentes :) Mas diz lá que não é uma boa maneira de os distinguir na fala: _quê de cão_ e _quê de nove_?

Comment: Mesmo :D Aqui dizemos "quê de cão e quê de qua qua". (como fazem os patos)

Comment: Essa também é boa: para eles se lembrarem como se escreve _quatro, qual_

Comment: Eu adicionei o "r" no nome da música mas precisa de no mínimo 6 caracteres diferentes, então adicionei o famoso alt+255... O problema é que isso alterou o link, poderia arrumar pra mim por favor?

Comment: Obrigado a todos os meus editores

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido `q de nove`, e fiquei ali confuso a pensar que era um erro tipográfico... quase corrigi. Eu aprendi "q de cauda", mas também já ouvi "q de quá-quá".

Comment: Lol, *q de nove* é capaz de ser uma coisa aqui dos mouros :) Eles é que introduziram os algarismos na Europa.