# Sobre o uso do presente literário, e.g. Camões é um patriota ferrenho

Tags: tempo-verbal

Participei [nesta discussão no ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295070/how-to-refer-to-dead-and-alive-persons-together/295072#295072) sobre o uso por autores anglófonos do que poderíamos chamar *presente literário*, ou seja, usar os tempos verbais do presente para discutir ideias expressas nas obras de autores mortos tal como se estes fossem ainda vivos. Em português, ninguém se escandalizaria, creio, com coisas como:

> Eça de Queiroz em *Os Maias* (1888) ***critica*** mordazmente a sociedade lisboeta de finais do século XIX.
>
> Machado de Assis em *Dom Casmurro* (1899) ***sai-se*** volta e meia com frases impagáveis como “toda a cara dele era pouca para a estupefação.”

Mas pergunto-me se é habitual ou aceitável ir em português tão longe como vão alguns autores anglófonos. Por exemplo, Kingsley Amis escrevendo em 1975 sobre Rudyard Kipling (1865-1936):

> [E]ven I, with my tiny knowledge of both fields, ***can catch Kipling out*** on the bull-fight and on naval gunnery. ***He is wrong*** about the manufacture of liqueurs, too (*Rudyard Kipling and His World*, Thames and Hudson, 1975, p. 81).
>
> [M]esmo eu, sabendo quase nada sobre qualquer dos assuntos, ***consigo apanhar Kipling em falso*** acerca de touradas e batalhas navais. ***Ele está*** também enganado acerca do fabrico de licores. [Minha tradução.]

Será impressão minha que em português nós somos mas comedidos no uso do presente literário? Por exemplo, nesta resposta a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/347/os-nomes-da-letra-g-n%C3%A3o-depende-na-regi%C3%A3o) eu escrevi acerca de afirmações de Duarte Nunes de Leão na sua Ortografia da Língua Portuguesa (1576):

> O insigne Duarte Nunes de Leão ***estava*** redondamente enganado acerca de termos recebido a pronunciação ***gê*** dos mouros

Seria aceitável dizer, “Duarte Leão ***está*** redondamente enganado?

Resumindo, o que eu gostaria de saber é se há exemplos deste uso ousado do presente literário na literatura em português, ou se há recomendações acerca do seu uso.

Comment: Já vi o uso do presente literário diversas vêzes.  Nas instituições de ensino superior é comum. No meu tempo de estudante eu ouvia: "Alexandre Herculano tem um linguajar cansativo";  "Shakespeare no original é muito difícil até para o falante nativo."; "Shakespeare usa muito certos recursos.....", "Camões é o grande poeta da Língua Portuguesa",  Com "O Crime do Padre Amaro" Eça de Queiroz prova que  é possível manter o frescor de uma obra...; Em "Gabriela, Cravo e Canela" Jorge Amado demonstra ter um conhecimento profundo sobre o modo de vida no sul da Bahia nos anos 20.  Coisas desse tipo.

Comment: Em uma palestra, soa bem dizer "Duarte leão está redondamente enganado quando afirma, em seu livro......... que ......"   No dia-a-dia, no entanto, acho que eu diria "estava".

Comment: Jacinto, para mim, «Camões» em «Camões é o melhor poeta» nem falamos **do** Camões falamos, falamos **de** Camões, ou seja, falamos do indivíduo imaginado, imaterial, Camões, o qual é factual, não tem vitalidade para morrer, senão vitalidade figurativa. Por outro exemplo, «A Alemanha ganhou a Copa», o que é Alemanha? Lugar, lugar não ganha copa. Governo? Nem governo. Está se falando do sentido imaginativo, imaterial, de Alemanha. Eis um exemplo interessante https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O_boW9YA7I.

Comment: Por sinal, pensei por algumas horas, e não consegui pensar em como explicá-lo direito, então ficou inobjetivo. Desculpa.

Comment: @Schilive, creio que até compreendi: dizes basicamente que o Camões de que falamos continua vivo? O argumento para o literary present tem semelhança: [use the present tense ... to discuss the actions and thoughts presented in the text. Do this because literature exists as a present phenomenon regardless of whether or not its author is alive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295070/how-to-refer-to-dead-and-alive-persons-together/295072#295072). A diferença é que eles dizem que a literatura continua a existir; tu dizes que é o próprio autor que ainda existe.