# Dialetos que conservam diferenças de sibilantes: na pronúncia, “sinto” ≠ “cinto”, “coser” ≠ “cozer”

Tags: fonologia, homofonia, dialetos

No português, há pares de consoantes sibilantes homófonas que são grafadas de maneiras diferentes por motivos históricos. São os seguintes pares:

- ⟨ch, x⟩, exemplo **feche** e **feixe**;
- ⟨s, z⟩ (o ⟨S⟩ simples-intervocálico), exemplo: **coser** e **cozer**;
- ⟨ss, ç⟩ (o ⟨S⟩ duplo-intervocálico; e o ⟨C⟩ palatizado/cedilhado), exemplo: **massa** e **maça**.

Ainda existem dialetos portugueses que conservem a diferença fonética de algum desses pares?

Ouvi dizer que na fronteira norte de Portugal, o ⟨ch⟩ tem som africado "tx" (ou o "tch" de "tchau"), talvez por influencia do Galego/Espanhol (que conservam a diferença desse par), mas não pude confirmar essa informação em nenhuma fonte fiável nem com nativos.

Comment: Sim, ainda se mantém o som africado "tx" em zonas fronteiriças de Trás-os-Montes, no Norte de Portugal. É uma pronúncia que está a cair em desuso. Ouve a pronúncia de "chamuscam-nos" aos 6 segundos desta recolha: http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/som4.html

Comment: Se me lembro bem, a distinção entre coser e cozer faz-se em Viseu (o nome desta cidade soa mais a /j/ do que a /z/). Pelo menos, assim ensinou-me um professor que era dali

Comment: No caso de Trás-os-Montes, seria mais por causa da segunda língua oficial de Portugal, o mirandês, não é?

Comment: @guifa não acho que seja. O mirandês é limitado a uma [zona muito pequena e limítrofe de Trás-os-Montes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_mirandesa#/media/File:Asturllion%C3%A9s_en_Tierra_de_Miranda.png). O "tx" também é usado na zona de Vila Real (conheço exemplos de Vila Pouca e Pedras Salgadas), por exemplo, que fica a 150km daí. ... pensando melhor, quero desdizer o "fronteiriças" dali do primeiro comentário. :)

Comment: @Seninha, tentei tornar o título mais "sexy". Vê se gostas.

Comment: Gostei. O exemplo deixou mais claro do que se trata.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O estudo de referência sobre o assunto é ainda a [“Nova Proposta de Classificação dos Dialectos Galego-Portugueses” de Lindley Cintra de 1971 (Instituto Camões)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/biblioteca/novaproposta.pdf). Este estudo baseia-se em dados recolhidos pelo autor nos anos 50, mas é ainda nele que se baseia a discussão do assunto na imensa *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian de 2013 (p. 88-104).

## Pronúncia diferenciada de *sinto/cinto, coser/cozer*, etc.

Segundo Lindley Cintra a pronúncia diferenciada nos pares *sinto/cinto, massa/maça, coser/cozer,* etc. ocorre nos falares transmontanos e alto-minhotos, no nordeste de Portugal. Pode ver-se [neste mapa no Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/mapa02.html) (zona a azul-claro). Mais abaixo na mesma página podem ouvir os dois ss em registos sonoros dessa região. O *c* seguido de *e* ou *i* e o *ç* segue a norma-padrão de Portugal e do Brasil, mas o *s* inicial ou *ss* intervocálico soa intermédio entre *ç* e *ch*.

Por exemplo, no registo de [Perafita 2](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/som7.html), o *c/ç* é pronunciado como na língua norma-padrão em *ouço* e *mocinha*, mas o *s* inicial/*ss* de *senhoras, Souto, missa, assim,* etc. é muito diferente, de tal forma que *missa* se aproxima de *micha*. O mesmo se passa com as variantes sonoras: o *z* em princípio de sílaba segue a norma-padrão, mas o *s* intervocálico aproxima-se do som de *j*; comparem no mesmo registo *reza* e *dizia* (norma-padrão) com *casa* e *coisa* (aproximam-se de *caja* e *coija*).

Para produzir estes “outros” ss, tentem pronunciar o *s* com a língua arqueada de tal modo que apenas a ponta se aproxima do céu da boca; por isso se chama apical, nomeadamente fricativa apicoalveolar sonora (*casa*) ou surda (*massa*); enquanto na pronúncia norma-padrão as fricativas são sempre pronunciadas aproximando uma parte maior da língua do céu da boca, chamando-se por isso fricativas alveolares pré-dorsais.

Explica a *Gramática do Português* (p. 96) que estas quatro fricativas eram a norma no português antigo. As apicoalveolares vieram do latim, onde já eram representadas por *s*; as pré-dorsais evoluíram também do latim, mas de sons representados do *c* e *t* quando seguidos de *e*, *æ*, *i* ou *y* (*Cicero, Cæsar, certus, gratia*, etc.); no latim clássico estes *c* e *t* eram mesmo pronunciados [k] e [t], mas começaram a evoluir para outros sons ainda no latim tardio, dando origem às nossas fricativas pré-dorsais, que eram representadas no português antigo por *c* (seguido de *e* ou *i*), *ç* ou *z* [(para a evolução do som de *ci, ce*, etc., ver esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/347/os-nomes-da-letra-g-n%C3%A3o-depende-na-regi%C3%A3o). Depois herdámos também palavras com este som do árabe.

Entretanto, exceto nos falares transmontanos e alto-minhotos, as quatro fricativas reduziram-se a duas, desaparecendo na pronúncia a diferença entre *sinto* e *cinto* ou *coser* e *cozer*. Nos dialetos meridionais, que se estendem até Aveiro, Coimbra e Castelo Branco [(ver mapa no Instituto Camões)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/mapa02.html) as fricativas apicoalveolares passaram a pré-dorsais, e foi esta a pronúncia que vingou no Brasil; entre esta região e a área dos falares transmontanos e alto-minhotos—uma área que inclui o Baixo Minho, Douro Litoral, Beira Alta e parte da Beira Baixa—foram as fricativas pré-dorsais que passaram a apicoalveolares; daí estas fricativas serem popularmente conhecidas em Portugal por *s beirão*.

## *Tch: tchave, tchuva*, etc.

Novamente segundo Lindley Cintra, a pronúncia de *ch*, mas não do *x*, como se fosse *tch* (*chave* como se fosse *tchave*, *bucho* como se fosse *butcho*) ocorre numa área que coincide aproximadamente com a do s beirão (os dois azuis no [mapa do Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/mapa02.html)), mas não completamente, não incluindo por exemplo o litoral dos distritos de Braga e Porto. Podem ver o mapa do Lindley Cintra na [“Nova Proposta” (p. 16)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/biblioteca/novaproposta.pdf), mas é difícil de ler.

### Persistência e declínio destas pronúncias

Note-se que estas pronúncias ocorrem nestas regiões, mas não quer dizer que sejam dominantes. A minha impressão de contactos com pessoas dessas zonas, é estas pronúncias são pouco comuns. Em particular, a respeito do *tch* diz a *Gramática do Português* (p. 92):

> Esta pronúncia, que é sentida como rústica, tem sido progressivamente eliminada. Conserva-se ainda, contudo, na pronúncia de pessoas idosas das aldeias […] materiais recolhidos posteriormente para o [*Atlas Linguístico e Etnográfico de Portugal e da Galiza*] revelam que, apesar de geralmente erradicado na fala das camadas jovens e adultas, ainda na última década do século XX, na área tradicional deste traço, pessoas que normalmente o omitem, pelo menos perante estranhos, na realidade ainda o conservam, deixando-o “escapar” na fala espontânea.

E já no final do século XIX, um observador comentava que a distinção *sinto/cinto, coser/cozer* estava a desaparecer na vila de Valpaços, bem no centro da região onde a diferença ocorre:

> Nesta minha terceira carta á cêrca do sub-dialecto valpacense completarei as informações [...]
>
> **13.** A distinção constante entre os valores de *ç* e *s* surdo, de *z* e *s* sonoro, que eu reputo, acompanhado o sr. Gonçalves Vianna, como caracterisitica phonetica do dialecto transmontano, vae desapparecendo nesta villa; facto de que o povo tem consciencia, pois diz de pessoa, que não faz esta distincção, ser *cidadosa*.
> (“Linguagem Popular de Valpaços”, *Revista Lusitana*, vol. III, 1895, p. 325, disponível no [Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/etnologia-etnografia-tradicoes.html).)

Comment: Lembrei dessa pergunta e me veio agora a dúvida seguinte. Em algum momento na história de nossa ortografia, foi decidido que o ⟨ç⟩ não seria mais usado em início de palavra, enquanto que ⟨ce, ci⟩ se mantiveram. Grafias como ⟨çapato⟩ tornaram-se ⟨sapato⟩, mas ⟨ciência⟩ manteve-se inalterada.  Os dialetos portugueses nordestinos (transmontano, etc.) perderam o /s/ apical no inicio de palavras (e essa reforma ortográfica seria um reflexo disso); ou estes dialeto ainda mantêm este som em posição inicial (e "sapato" é pronunciado como se possuísse ⟨ç⟩ independente da ortografia)?

Comment: @Seninha, creio que a substituição do *ç* inicial por *s* não teve nada que ver com a pronúncia dos nordestinos. A primeira grafia aprovada por lei foi a de [1911 em Portugal (base X)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&version=1911), que explicitamente limita o uso do *ç* ao interior das palavras e, com esta exceção, prescreve *c,ç/s,ss* de acordo com a etimologia. Antes disso usava-se a chamada grafia etimológica (*sciencia, hypothese, escriptor*), mas o uso do *ç* inical já era raro no sXIX; mesmo no sXVIII *sapato* era bem mais comum que *çapato*.

Comment: Mas, nesses dialetos, "sapato" (ou outras palavras que eram iniciadas por ⟨ç⟩ cedilhado, creio que não são muitas) continua a ser pronunciado como *çapato* (pré-dorsal) ou é *"x"apato* (apico-velar)? Pois a impressão que tenho, é que essas palavras mantêm a pronuncia pré-dorsal independente da ortografia. Infelizmente não encontrei nenhuma dessas pronúncias nos registros sonoros do site do Instituto Camões.

Comment: @Seninha, também não encontrei nesses registos nenhuma palavra que já tivesse começado por *ç*. Mas há uma senhora ou senhoras que falam com as 4 fricativas e pronunciam *centeio* (Outeiro 1) e *cima* (Outeiro 2) com pré-dorsal, o que me leva a crer que pronunciariam também *sapato* com pré-dorsal. Não encontrei  qualquer menção de uma exceção na pronúncia das fricativas iniciais. Para a maioria dos falantes o *ç* (inicial ou medial) foi mantido por tradição escrita (já que fundiram as 4 fricativas em 2).  >>

Comment: >> Penso que o abandono do ç inicial na escrita tenha sido uma opção estética, mas duvido que isso possa ter influenciado a pronúncia. Até porque até princípio do sXX  a grande maioria da população rural em Portugal era analfabeta.

Comment: @Seninha, a Revista Lusitana é uma fonte inesgotável de informação: na tal carta também vem uma observação acerca das sibilantes em Valpaços, que juntei à resposta

Comment: E olha... Em Valpaços ainda se diz "ũa", como cá. O texto diz que lá ainda se diferencia "ch ~ x" mas não diz se está a cair em desuso. Essa revista é realmente interessante, obrigado por mostrá-la!