# Por que palavras de origem Tupi usam ⟨ç⟩ em vez de ⟨ss⟩?

Tags: ortografia, fonologia

No vocabulário brasileiro existem muitas palavras que, no Tupi, possuiam o som de /s/ (como em ***s***aca e *ca**ç**a*) e foram inseridas no dicionário português com o C-cedilha ⟨ç⟩ ou o C-palatalizado ⟨ce, ci⟩. Por exemplo: "paçoca", "açai", cipó, "jacaré-açu", "minhocoçu", cupuaçu (e várias outras palavras com o sufixo "-açu/-oçu"). Pergunto por que, como no tupi não havia uma diferença fonética tal como a representada pelo ⟨s, c⟩ no Português, optaram por uma letra cujo som é sensível ao contexto (ca vs. ce) em vez da opção óbvia ⟨s⟩ ou ⟨ss⟩, que representa o mesmo som?

Minhas opções são:

- Quando o tupi foi escrito, ainda havia a diferença na pronúncia entre o par ⟨ss, ç/c⟩ no dialeto dos portugueses colonizadores e/ou dos padres jesuítas que documentaram a língua local; daí preferiu-se usar a grafia ⟨ç⟩ por ser a grafia do português que melhor representava o som `/s/` tupi.
- O par ⟨ss, ç⟩ já era homófono aos colonizadores, mas preferiu-se grafar o tupi com ⟨ç⟩ por outro motivo qualquer (e qual seria?).

Nesta [gramática tupi](https://archive.org/details/artedegrammatica01figu), do padre jesuíta Luis Figueira, publicada em Lisboa em 1687, usa-se a grafia ⟨ç⟩. O padre jesuíta José de Anchieta escreveu o seguinte, no primeiro parágrafo de seu [livro sobre a língua local](http://etnolinguistica.wdfiles.com/local--files/biblio%3Aanchieta-1595-arte/anchieta_1595_arte_mindlin.pdf):

> Nesta lingoa do Brasil não ha f, l, s, z, rr dobrado nem muda com liquida, *ut* cra, pra, etc. Em lugar do s *in principio* ou *medio dictionis*, serve ç com zeura, *ut* Açô, çatâ. [sic]

O que seria um "s in principio ou medio dictiones" e um "ç com zeura"? E por que esse tal "ç com zeura" era diferente do ⟨ç⟩ normal?

Comment: Encontrei [esta "tradução" desse trecho do José Anchieta](http://www.etnolinguistica.org/arte): Nesta língua do Brasil não há f, l, s, z, rr nem (encontro de consoante) muda com (consoante) líquida, como cra, pra, etc. Em lugar do s no início ou no meio da palavra, serve ç, como açô [a-só], çatâ [s-atá].

Comment: Então o dialeto dos jesuítas tinham a diferença s/ç, a ponto de ser notável em outras línguas?  Eu pensava que essa diferença tinha se perdido no sul de Portugal antes da colonização e já teria chegado ao Brasil (e demais colônias) como par homófono.

Comment: *Zeura* parece significa 'cedilha'. Vê [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-GYaAQAAIAAJ&q=zeura&dq=zeura&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwn-C-wqfVAhWFCBoKHdPGCsIQ6AEISDAF) e também [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=XN4OAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=zeura&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwn-C-wqfVAhWFCBoKHdPGCsIQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=zeura&f=false).

Comment: Fui eu que escrevi que "foi esta a pronúncia [com fricativas só pré-dorsais] que foi para o Brasil"; é mais cauteloso dizer que foi essa pronúncia que vingou também no Brasil. De qualquer modo os tipos que escreveram o tupi chegaram ao Brasil já adultos e numa fase muito inicial da colonização.

Comment: Para complicar, José Anchieta (1534-97) era das Canárias; foi estudar para Coimbra já aos 14 anos, e foi para o Brasil aos 19. O que ele chama "mudas" são provavelmente as oclusivas; vê [*Ortografia* do Duarte Nunes de Leão (1576) f. 6 (acerca de d e t)](http://purl.pt/15/3/#/10); vê também b, g e q. Ele sugere também que distingue o som de s do ç [f. 23 esquerda](http://purl.pt/15/3/#/27): z "soa entre .s. & .ç. A qual letra, porque muitos vulgares a confundem com o .s. & aas vezes com o .ç. E [aqui](http://purl.pt/15/3/#/9) diz que ç soa como uma "specie de .z." Mas ele é complicado.

Comment: @Seninha - seria muito curioso que a língua ainda tivesse uma oposição s/ç no tempo de Anchieta, e viesse a perder essa oposição em *ambos* os lados do Atlântico. Mais razoável é supor que o "ç" do tupi tivesse um som diferente, depois assimilado ao /s/ português...

Comment: @LuísHenrique, na verdade o som tupi sempre foi /s/, sem nenhuma contraparte sibilante, mas foi escrito segundo as regras ortográficas do português daquela épica. E as palavras adquiridas ao vocabulário brasileiro (*saci*, *açaí*) ainda mantém essa ortografia.

Comment: O "in principio ou medio dictiones" não seria no início ou meio da palavra? Os exemplos parecem indicar isso.

Comment: @Luís , muita gente já não fazia a distinção s/ç no sXVI (já é comum nessa época *Brasil* e *Brazil*, trocar *massa* por *maça*, e coisas assim). Mas a oposição persistiu nalgumas regiões de Portugal até basicamente ao presente, e nalgumas regiões a convergência foi para o "s" (/s/ apicoavelar) e não para o "ç" do padrão; vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%c3%a7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%c3%bancia-sinto-%e2%89%a0-cinto). >>

Comment: >> Portanto parece-me quase certo que terão chegado ao Brasil nos sXVI e XVII portugueses com diversos sotaques, uns com o /s/ do padrão atual, outros com o apicoavelar, e ainda outros que faziam ainda a oposição.

Answer (score 3):

A pseudorresposta que encontro é que simplesmente **é a regra**. Parece ser bem estabelecido (ver, e.g., [1](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/cedilha.html), [2](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-com-c/), [3](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/cedilha.htm), [4](https://www.todamateria.com.br/uso-do-c-cedilha/), [5](https://sol.sapo.pt/artigo/65273/linguista-brasileiro-diz-que-acordo-ortografico-ja-e-antigo-e-defende-simplificacao), [6](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/por-que-mucarela-se-escreve-com-c.html), [7](https://www.infoenem.com.br/surgiu-a-duvida-e-com-c-por-que/)) que se prefere a cedilha em

> palavras de origem árabe, italiana, africana e *indígena*

E aqui vale observar que não é portanto só no tupi e no guarani, mas também em outras línguas indígenas que se usa o *ç* (outro exemplo é o [kaipó](https://www.dicionariotupiguarani.com.br/kaiapo/)).

Claro que isto apenas altera a pergunta do título para algo como

> O que motivou a regra de se usar a cedilha em muitas palavras estrangeiras?

E para essa não tenho resposta!

O outro assunto da pergunta - a fonética dos portugueses da época e dos indígenas - é complicado e não parece ter resposta unânime pelas publicações que pude encontrar.

Dentre os complicadores, vários já mencionados na pergunta e comentários, se destacam:

- a qualidade de muitas fontes, inclusive de primárias, por vezes é questionável;
- não se trata de uma língua, mas de muitas;
- o tupi é língua viva, não é estática, então mesmo uma descrição correta se refere não apenas a um grupo em particular de falantes, mas a um tempo em particular;
- a fala indígena, especialmente dentre aqueles que mais contato tinham com os estrangeiros, era provavelmente influenciada por suas línguas - ao ponto de uma nova língua se desenvolver, o "brasiliano", ou [língua-geral](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_geral_(Brasil)).

As publicações mais relevantes que encontrei defendem posições díspares. Por exemplo, Mansur Guérios [defende](http://doi.org/10.5380/rel.v29i0.19410) [1] que os sons de *s* e *ç* eram distintos na época:

> O estudo explica por que o fonema (**s** de vocábulos tupis introduzidos no léxico português não é transcrito com **s** (ou **ss**), mas com **c** (+ **e**, **i**) e **ç**. O fato se baseia na existência do fonema africano / **ts** /, no século 16, tanto no tupi quanto no português, neste representado pelas grafias **c** (+ **e**, **i**) e **ç**.

Enquanto o, aparentemente mais conceituado e melhor embasado, Edelweiss escreve em sua [sequência de artigos](http://www.etnolinguistica.org/artigo:edelweiss-1969-guasu/p/3) [2] quase sempre (mas há exceções) com **s** em tupi, explicitando no início da obra que "tem o valor [fonêmico] de *ss*", e com **ç** em português e brasiliano (e.g., "ygûasú" -> iguaçu). Um excerto da página 37:

```
   Brasiliano         Forma Tupi         Tradução Portuguêsa   

abá angaipaba oçú - abâ agaipab-eté   - pessoa terrível, tirano;   
abá karimbab oçú  - abá kyreymbá-katú - valentão;   
abá guaçú         - abá-gúasú         - grande homem, ilustre;   
abaiba oçú        - abai-katú         - abrasador, destruidor;   
anama oçú         - anam-usú          - basto, fechado (mato, capim);   
apyá oçú          - apyab-usú         - valoroso;
```

[1] "[Transcrição portuguesa de um fonema tupi](https://revistas.ufpr.br/letras/article/view/19410)", Revista Letras vol. *29* (1980), p. 129.
[2] "[Gûaçú e usú na diacronia das línguas e dialetos Tupi-Guaranis](http://www.etnolinguistica.org/artigo:edelweiss-1969-guasu/p/3)", Revista do Instituto de Estudos Brasileiros: n. 7 (1969), p. 33-45; n. 8 (1970), p. 51-64; n. 9 (1970), p. 65-80; n. 10 (1971), p. 29-62; n. 11 (1972), p. 77-89; n. 12 (1972), p. 59-78.

Comment: Resposta excelente.

Comment: @stafusa, esta resposta deixou-me um bocado desconsolado. A fonética dos portuguese no sXVI não é “outro assunto”, é uma questão central. Houve no português antigo dois sons diferentes, um representado por *s, ss* (/s/ apicoavelar), outro por *ç, c(e, i)* (/s/ pré-dorsal); vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%c3%a7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%c3%bancia-sinto-%e2%89%a0-cinto?rq=1). Precisamente uma possibilidade, a que a pergunta alude, é que os colonizadores que escreveram o tupi achassem que o /s/ do tupi era prédorsal.

Comment: Agora, tu citas Guérios,  que o *ç* representava no português o fonema /ts/. Pensa-se que este fonema existiu na evolução do latim para o *ç* no português; agora que ele persistisse no sXVI foi a primeirissimamente que ouvi. No sXVI muitos falantes já não faziam a antiga diferença entre *ss* e *ç*, coisa que já tinha começado no sXIII, portanto muito me espanta que o /ts/ ainda existisse na altura. Não me aumenta a confiança o Guérios chamar ao /ts/ *fonema africano* — é *africado*. Não sei se leste além do abstract, se sabes se isto foi um engano só ali ou se persiste no resto do texto?

Comment: Ou eu não percebi, ou o Edelweiss simplesmente optou por grafar com *s* palavras indígenas que em português se grafam com *ç*. Mas isso diz-nos alguma coisa acerca da fonética antiga? Nós termos coisas como *massa* e *maça* deve-se exclusivamente à história particular do português. Atualmente não há razão fonética para as grafias diferentes.

Comment: A tua regra inicial apoia-se em fontes (que tu numeras 1 a 7) que não me inspiram confiança nenhuma. São artigos genéricos sobre a cedilha. Duvido que na adaptação ao português de palavras do árabe, italiano, línguas africanas e indígenas, o *ç* fosse uma mera preferência. O português antigo conviveu diretamente com o árabe numa altura em que a distinção fonética entre *ss* e *ç* ainda era a norma. Então o pessoal ia escrever com *ç* só por preferência e não por o som árabe ser o pré-dorsal que os portugueses representavam com *ç*? >>

Comment: >> E mais tarde, na adaptação do italiano, não atenderiam ao som e grafia na língua original. Então *serralho* e *fracasso* (de origem italiana) são exceções ou já se grafaram *cerralho* e *fracaço*? Um dos artigos lincados estende a regra a adaptações de todas as línguas estrangeiras! Seria preciso mais crítica e critério na apreciação e seleção das fontes para responder a esta pergunta.

Comment: Eu entendo, @Jacinto, tuas críticas. Por isso, por exemplo, digo "***parece** ser bem estabelecido*", apesar das numerosas fontes: simplesmente não fui capaz de encontrar fonte melhor online - mas tampouco encontrei crítica à afirmação e, como menciono, palavras de outras línguas indígenas frequentemente são grafadas com "ç", e não é nada óbvio que isso possa se deve à fonologia  dessas diferentes línguas. E chamo a questão de "outro assunto da pergunta", por não ser mencionado no título e pela resposta a este ser possivelmente independente da tal questão.

Comment: Sobre o Guérios, sim, também não me inspirou muita confiança, mas limitei minha crítica a um indireto "[o Edelweiss é] aparentemente mais conceituado e melhor embasado", pois não tenho base para fazer uma crítica muito mais veemente. Mas o "africano" pode ser ou não um *typo*, mas não volta a aparecer no texto (na minha leitura diagonal). Quanto a Edelweiss, ele mostra clara preocupação com a pronúncia original indígena, e seria então surpreendente se a escolha do "s" para denotar o som "ss" fosse arbitrária.

Comment: Sobre o italiano, os exemplos dados nas páginas dão a entender que o "ç" é a escolha para a transcrição moderna, em que haveria a tal regra explícita para seguir, não para todas as palavras de origem italiana incorporadas há tempos. De novo: não ponho minha mão no fogo pela tal regra; apenas não vejo aqui nenhuma clara contradição.

Comment: Mas o Edelweiss diz que escolheu o *s* em vez do *ç* por o *s* representar melhor o som no tupi? Se for, ele há de dizer, não? Muito me surpreenderia que fosse isso. Não há razão intrinsecamente fonética para o s representar o /s/ apicoavelar, e o ç o pré-dorsal; isso foi um "acidente" histórico no português antigo, possivelmente com paralelos noutras línguas latinas (o s no latim era apicoavelar; o /s/ pré-dorsal evoluiu de palavras como Cícero, que no latim clássico se pronunciavam como Quiquero).

Comment: Não sei, @Jacinto. A literatura relevante que conheço são esses dois artigos, meu conhecimento de fonética é bastante limitado e o da evolução da fonética portuguesa mais ainda - se resume a pouco mais do que li por aqui mesmo. Minha resposta é a de um leigo interessado que investiu um pouco de tempo nessa questão - não é à toa que chamo a primeira parte da minha postagem de "pseudorresposta", e que na segunda não apresento conclusão alguma, apenas apresento o que pude encontrar a respeito.