# Por que o som do "S" das línguas indígenas no Brasil foram registrados com "Ç"?

Tags: ortografia

Por qual motivo os portugueses adotaram o "Ç"  para escrever em português o som do "S" das línguas indígenas?

Já li em algum lugar se tratar de uma prática comum dos portugueses, e nesta prática predominava o uso do "Ç" para o som do "S" ao escrever em português palavras estrangeiras.

Mas qual a origem disso? Quem inaugurou essa prática? Foi (ainda é) uma regra universal entre os países lusófonos?

No caso das palavras de línguas indígenas brasileiras há talvez centenas de exemplos, mas alguns:

- Paçoca
- Paiçandu
- Piaçaguera
- Açaí
- Paraguaçu

Palavras do árabe:

- Açougue
- Muçulmano

Comment: [Por que palavras de origem Tupi usam ⟨ç⟩ em vez de ⟨ss⟩?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4627/2759)