# Por que, no exterior, Brasil é escrito com Z?

Tags: ortografia

Recentemente estava lendo — a título de curiosidade — a [constituição de 1824](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/constituicao/constituicao24.htm) e me deparei com o seguinte artigo:

> Art. 1. O IMPERIO do Brazil é a associação Politica de todos os Cidadãos Brazileiros. Elles formam uma Nação livre, e independente, que não admitte com qualquer outra laço algum de união, ou federação, que se opponha á sua Independencia.

É inegável que a ortografia mudou bastante de lá para cá, logo surgiram duas dúvidas sobre essas mudanças:

1. Por que a palavra Brazil passou a ser escrita com “S”?
2. Por que outros países não seguiram a nova ortografia e passaram a se referir ao Brasil com “S”?

Comment: Li em alguns sites que é devido o som do “S”, mas acredito que isso não tem relação.

Comment: É um "acho", mas Brasil em português é com . Antigamente era com Z e com acordos se definiu com S. Porém, tem som de Z. Na maioria das linguas, S tem som de S e Z tem som de Z. Por isso, se escreve com Z. Lembrando que por exemplo em Francês, se escreve Brésil. https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/brasil-com-z/12135

Comment: @Peixoto No caso do inglês, algumas palavras com “S” possuem o som de “Z”, por exemplo: ba**s**ic. Ps.: Não tinha me atentado para a escrita em Francês. :)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr ("basic" tem som de "S", ao contrário do português. Um exemplo podia ser "phra**s**e".) A respeito da pergunta original, vejo que a escritura "Brasil" existia na altura no Portugal. Veja esta imagem da [Carta de Lei de 16 de Dezembro de 1815](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:Carta_de_Lei_de_16_de_Dezembro_de_1815_29.jpg). A transcrição tem "Bra**z**il", mas na imagem se pode verifica que este "z" é diferente do "z" de "fa**z**er" e "rique**z**a", e igual ao "s" de  "precio**s**os" e "me**s**mo".

Comment: Sobre a pergunta 2, provavelmente é porque os países não acompanham (nem poderíamos esperar que acompanhassem) as mudanças ortográficas e de dialetos dos outro países. Basta ver Pequim, cuja forma preferida hoje é Beijing, mas nós provavelmente manteremos o nome Pequim por um bom tempo, talvez em paralelo com Beijing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Originalmente escrevia-se com **s**, já antes da viagem do Cabral, quando *brasil*—ou *brasill* ou *brasyll*—designava apenas o pigmento. Vê [esta pergunta sobre a origem do nome *Brasil*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4746/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-brazil-brasil-in-modern-portuguese/4755#4755). Mas a partir do século XVI, pela altura em que *Brasil* se tornou também nome de terra, passa a encontra-se, em português, quer *Brasil* quer *Brazil*.

Isto aconteceu com muitas outras palavras: encontra-se a partir dessa altura *brasa* e *braza*, *cousa* e *couza*, etc. Também acontece o contrário, palavras que agora se escrevem com **z**, aparecem noutros séculos escritas ora com **s** ora com **z**: por exemplo, *prazer* e *praser*. No português medieval o **s** e o **z** representavam sons diferentes, mas com o passar do tempo os dois sons fundiram-se num só (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%C3%A7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%C3%BAncia-sinto-%E2%89%A0-cinto)), o que facilitou o surgimento destas duplas grafias. Só com as reformas ortográficas do princípio do século XX, 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil, é que estas duplas grafias foram eliminadas, ficando apenas a variante etimologicamente correta, que no nosso caso é *Brasil*.

Agora, por que é que no exterior se preferiu *Brazil*. Bem, primeiro, não é no exterior todo. Entre as línguas de origem europeia mais faladas, só em inglês é que é com **z**. Em espanhol, francês, italiano e alemão é também com **s**. As palavras espanhola (*Brasil*), francesa (*Brésil*) e italiana (*Brasile*) também já designavam o pigmento antes da chegada do Cabral ao Brasil. Creio que a grafia inglesa *Brazil* se deve a influência da variante portuguesa. Talvez do século XVI ao XIX *Brazil* fosse mais comum que *Brasil*. No entanto os dicionários, já desde 1712, sempre preferiram *Brasil*.