# How did “a pesar de” signify “in spite of”?

Tags: origem-histórica

In Spanish and Portuguese, *a pesar de* means *in (de)spite of*. But in both languages, *pesar* has never meant *spite*. *pesar* hails from [Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin) *[*pēsāre](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Latin/pesare&action=edit&redlink=1)*, from Classical [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[pēnsāre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pensare#Latin)*. But then how does *pesar* yield the meaning *in spite of*?

Answer (score 4):

Funny enough *pesar* comes ultimately from Latin [*pendere*, which (see Lewis & Short's *Latin Dictionary*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=pendo)) meant “*to cause to hang down, to suspend*; esp[ecialy] of scales in weighing;” and hence [*pensare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=penso), which is the frequentative of *pendere*, meant ’to weigh’ (also ’to ponder, consider’).

*Pensare* became *pesar* in Portuguese (except in the sense ’to think’, which appeared later in Medieval Latin; see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penso#Latin)). But in addition to the Classical Latin senses, ***pesar*** added the meaning **’to cause sorrow, to sadden, to cause a feeling of oppression’**, and became also a noun meaning **’great sadness, sorrow.’** (see [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/pesar) of [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pesar/)). According to Houaiss dictionary these new senses existed in the 1200s already. Presumably we got them from ’to weigh’ because sadness can be seen as a weight that oppresses you. So in Old Galician-Portuguese, ***a pesar de*** (now *apesar de* in modern Portuguese) would quite literally mean **’to the sorrow of’**, and so **’against the will of’** (you could also say *a meu/teu/seu/etc. pesar*)and hence ’notwithstanding’ (see this [*Glosario da poesía medieval profana galego-portuguesa*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/2663)).

Now, **to compare with** [***in (de)spite of***, according to Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=despite) it meant originally ’in defiance or contempt of’ (the prepositional use of *despite* is short for *in despite of*, and [*spite*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=spite) was shortened from *despite*); *despite* meaning ’contemptuous challenge, defiance; act designed to insult or humiliate someone’ scorn, contempt;’ from Old French *despit*, ultimately from Latin *despectus*, ’act of looking down on, scorn, contempt’.

So if X is a potential obstacle to your doing something, but you do it anyway, in English you do it in spite of X, or in contempt of X; whereas in Portuguese we do it *apesar de* X, or ’to the sadness of’ X.

### If you want to go into details

I think native Portuguese speakers can easily make sense of *apesar* (if we bother to think about it at all) because everyone knows *pesar* means ’sadness.’ But we no longer say *apesar*, or even *a pesar*, to mean ’to the sadness of;’ we would say *para pesar de* instead, as in:

> João rompeu o noivado e entrou para um convento, para grade pesar de sua mãe
> João broke off his engagement and joined a convent, to the great sorrow of his mother

We no longer say *apesar* to mean ’against the will of’ either. For instance, to say João married against the will of his parents, we would say *João casou contra vontade dos pais* or *apesar da oposição dos pais*; just *apesar dos pais* would sound strange. But ’against the will’ is still how Portuguese dictionaries of the 1600s (our earliest) define *a pesar*. They are Portuguese-Latin dictionaries and render *a pesar* as Latin *invite* or *invitus* (see this [1619 one](https://books.google.pt/books?id=87dRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA266&dq=apesar%20inuitus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8zsqryNn1AhUELBoKHZS1DUMQ6AF6BAgUEAI#v=onepage&q=apesar%20inuitus&f=false) and [this 1647 one](https://books.google.pt/books?id=e6DyxVG39WIC&pg=PA12&dq=%22Aperto%20i%20perigo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJsMj1vNv1AhUKuRoKHTTOBscQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Aperto%20i%20perigo%22&f=false)), which according to [Lewis and Short Dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=invitus) means “against one’s will, unwilling, reluctant.” The [1611 Agostinho Barbosa dictionary](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1MAYBSt6acAC&pg=PA95&dq=A%20pezar,%20i,%20contra%20a%20vontade&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkrcvUutv1AhUW3IUKHRj0BIgQ6AF6BAgOEAI#v=onepage&q=A%20pezar%2C%20i%2C%20contra%20a%20vontade&f=false) is quite explicit:

[image]

(It is spelled *a pezar*: by this time people were already mixing up *s* and *z*, as in *Brasil* and *Brazil*; see [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/por-que-no-exterior-brasil-%C3%A9-escrito-com-z/5245#5245).)

For an actual example of the old usage see the following verses from this [late 1200s/early 1300s “cantiga de amor”](https://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=871&pv=sim). Folks at the Universidade Nova de Lisboa explain  *a pesar de mim* as “para meu pesar, contra minha vontade”  (’to my sorrow, against my will’; follow the link and click on the icons for the explanations; my English translation):

> Nostro Senhor, assi El me perdom:            Our Lord, so He may forgive me
> nom me deu morte, que de coraçom,          hasn’t given me death, which from my heart
> Lhe roguei sempr’e muito Lha pedi,           I always begged of Him and asked of Him
> mais deu-me vida, **a pesar de mim**           but gave me life, **to my sorrow/against my will**

There are many more examples in the [*Glosario da poesía medieval profana galego-portuguesa*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/2663).

Now, only people can feel sorrow or have will, and early on, accordingly, you only find *a pesar de* someone, not something. I looked up this [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) and the earliest examples of *apesar de* something I found are from the 1500s as in [“a pesar do mal que me resiste” (Camões)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=goBJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA60-IA1&dq=%22pesar%20do%20mal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1usvc9dn1AhWDzIUKHai6C84Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22pesar%20do%20mal%22&f=false) (’despite the evil that resists me’), [“a pesar dos ventos” (João de Barros)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=np9YfjUT_WkC&pg=PA69-IA1&dq=%22pesar%20dos%20ventos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMg53z9Nn1AhV8AWMBHWN3Bc4Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22pesar%20dos%20ventos%22&f=false) (’despite the winds’), [“a pesar de quantos inconvenientes ante mi vejo”](https://archive.org/details/comdiaeufrosin00vascuoft/page/n111/mode/2up?q=pesar&view=theater) (’despite the inconveniences I see before me’.

Looking at this [Spanish Corpus (CORDE)](https://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html), *a pesar* developed similarly, except that I find a few *a pesar de* something in the late 1300s already (*a pesar de* someone from the mid-1100s).

Now curiously, to mean  ’I do something with great sadness, against my heart's desire,’ in Old Portuguese people could say I do it *a meu pesar* or *a pesar de mim* (see this [cantiga de amor](https://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=1139&pv=sim)); in English you can say you did it *with a heavy heart*. It’s sort of the same weight metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

*Despite* or *in spite of* comes from *en dépit de* in French which comes from the Latin *despectus*: to look at something from top to bottom, i.e. examine thoroughly.

And a pesar de is from the Latin *pensare* and means to determine the weight of something. It's funny as the logic is great. I weigh something and then determine if that thing is the right thing,

So, they both relate to examining something closely or thoroughly.

:)

Comment: Lambie, do you know if in English "to weigh" can also mean to examine something?

Answer (score -2):

- Olá, é minha primeira resposta por aqui, tentarei ajudar!
- Hi, that's my first answer, I'll try to help!

The correct should be "apesar" - "a"+"pesar" (together)
You can see that in this song from Chico Buarque, called "Apesar de você".

But, you can see in this [dictionary](https://www.aulete.com.br/pesar) that "apesar de" can be "pesar de", the "a" falls, haha. They are equivalent, like posted before.

https://lyricstranslate.com/en/apesar-de-voc%C3%AA-spite-you.html

So, "apesar de", matches "in spite of" in English.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao site, BritoR e obrigado pela contribuição, mas perceba que você não responde à pergunta "how does pesar yield the meaning in spite of?". Ótimo você ter citado fontes, isso certamente contribui para a qualidade de uma resposta, mas nesse caso um dicionário teria sido mais apropriado (por exemplo [este](https://www.aulete.com.br/pesar), que inclusive nota que "pesar de" é sinônimo de "apesar de", o que complementaria tua postagem).

Comment: [So, X **matches** Y and English, with a capital e.]