# Escreve-se “Qatar”, “Quatar”, “Catar” ou “Katar”?

Tags: ortografia, nomes

Quando anunciaram que haveria a Copa no Qatar, vi *Qatar*, mas, agora, já vi *Qatar*, *Katar*, *Catar* e mais.

Então pergunto: qual é o nome correto? *Qatar*, *Quatar*, *Katar*, *Catar*, ou outra coisa?

Comment: Em Português, é Catar, com C. Em outras línguas, é diferente (Q, K, etc) - da mesma forma que Brasil é Brazil em inglês... O motivo, não sei dizer...

Comment: @Leonardo, no passado também se escreveu *Brazil* em português: vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/por-que-no-exterior-brasil-%c3%a9-escrito-com-z) ou [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4746/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-brazil-brasil-in-modern-portuguese).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Formalmente, a escrita correta é Catar, com C.

A página sobre o Catar na Wikipedia aceita duas definições: Catar (que aparentemente é a mais comum) e Qatar. Ao meu ver, o critério mais decisivo é o da Academia Brasileira de Letras, [que não reconhece a palavra Qatar em seu motor de busca](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario), mas reconhece Catar como um substantivo (o que é importante, pois não pode ser confundido com o verbo "catar"). O mesmo acontece no [motor de busca do Instituto Internacional da Língua Portuguesa](https://voc.iilp.cplp.org/index.php).

A palavra Qatar, por outro lado, não é reconhecida formalmente, mas aparece em alguns documentos oficiais, como [um decreto da Câmara dos Deputados do Brasil, relativo ao Tratado de Proibição Completa de Armas Nucleares](https://www2.camara.leg.br/legin/fed/decleg/1998/decretolegislativo-64-2-julho-1998-361727-publicacaooriginal-1-pl.html), aprovado em 1996, que menciona o Catar utilizando sua pronúncia internacional, com o Q. Apesar de se tratar de um documento oficial, não significa que o nome foi escrito corretamente, mas alguns podem argumentar que isso traz certa legitimidade ao nome internacional.

Minha conclusão é a seguinte: o nome correto é Catar, com C. Além do reconhecimento de duas grandes instituições da Língua Portuguesa, utilizar a letra Q com o som de K sem estar acompanhada da letra U é algo raro, senão ausente, na Língua Portuguesa formalizada. Por outro lado, veículos de mídia ou jornalistas eventualmente irão se referir ao país com a letra Q, uma vez que esta maneira de escrita é popular internacionalmente e evita ambiguidades.

Note que este não é um fenômeno raro. A cidade de Nova Iorque, por exemplo, possui sua escrita formalizada com "I" e "QUE", mas o termo Nova York ainda continua sendo muito comum na escrita popular e em veículos de mídia. Ou seja, o nome "oficial", apesar de já padronizado e formalizado na Língua Portuguesa, nem sempre será o mais utilizado ou o de mais fácil utilização.

Comment: Obrigado, Evandro! Achei que *Qatar* fosse mais conhecida. Interessante.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, Leandro, e não se esqueça de votar (tanto positiva quanto negativamente) as postagens!

Answer (score -1):

Na minha modesta opinião, Catar é um verbo cuja primeira vogal é de leitura fechada. Só no sotaque do Brasil é que tem leitura de vogal aberta.
Sendo que internacionalmente é conhecida por Qatar, com leitura de vogal aberta, deve ser assim escrita, também, em português. Quanto aos cidadãos do Qatar, estes são caterenses, com C, em português escrito e falado.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas não entendi uma coisa. Nunca ouvi de um nome internacional, senão os nomes em latim dos seres vivos. Está falando do inglês? O inglês é uma língua franca, mas ela não é uma língua internacional. Ainda assim, obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências.