# Por que Brasil em francês se escreve com E? Brésil

Tags: português-brasileiro

[Todos sabemos do Brazil com z](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/por-que-no-exterior-brasil-%C3%A9-escrito-com-z), mas uma duvida que me bateu agora e não encontrei resposta é por que em francês falam Bresil?

Comment: Obrigado pelo contributo breve, @Lambie :), mas evitemos responder em comentários: «Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.» A um comentário não posso editar para melhorar, ou discutir correções.

Answer (score 5):

Porque a palavra francesa *brésil* é mais antiga que o país!

[Dictionnaire de l’Académie française, 9ᵉ édition (actuelle)](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9B2090):

> ## BRÉSIL nom masculin
>
> > **xɪɪᵉ siècle.** Dérivé de *breze*, forme ancienne de *braise*, par analogie de couleur.
>
> Bois exotique qui, séché et pulvérisé, donne une matière tinctoriale rouge. *Brésil de Pernambouc, de Sainte-Lucie, du Japon*.

Ou seja, deriva da palavra *breze* em francês antigo, a forma antiga de *braise* (=brasa), por analogia com a cor. Escrevem [no artigo da Wikipédia francesa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%A9sil) sobre tudo isso:

> Les racines étymologiques du terme « Brésil » remontent au Moyen Âge. Le Brésil est, au XIIᵉ siècle, le nom d’un **colorant rouge** extrait d’un arbre indien et souvent utilisé dans la peinture européenne pour réaliser des glacis roses et rouges. ... La théorie la plus communément admise est que le mot « Brésil » tire son origine du bois de Brésil ou pernambouc, très apprécié dès le Moyen Âge pour ses propriétés tinctoriales, dont les Portugais reconnurent la présence en quantité lors de leur première exploration du pays.

Ou mais ou menos:

> As raízes etimológicas do termo francês *Brésil* remontam à Idade Média. No século XII o termo francês *le brésil* (já) era o nome de um **corante vermelho** extraído de uma árvore indígena e muito usado na pintura européia para fazer esmaltes rosa e vermelho. ... A teoria mais aceita é que a palavra francesa *Brésil* se origina do *“bois de Brésil ou pernambouc”* (pau-brasil), muito valorizado desde a Idade Média por as suas propriedades tintoriais, cuja presença os portugueses reconheceram em quantidade durante a sua primeira exploração do país.

Comment: Em francês antigo, *[bresil](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/bresil)* também significava braseiro (francês moderno: *brasier*). Ambos são foneticamente próximos de *braseiro* e *[Brasil](https://www.dicionarioetimologico.com.br/brasil/)* (cor de brasa).

Comment: "Dérivé de breze" doens't explain the accent in Brésil at all. And you might want to correct colorante.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o dicionário da [Academia Francesa](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9B2090) (*l'Académie Française*), a palavra ‘*brésil*’ vem de ‘*breze*’, que é uma forma do francês antigo de ‘*braize*’, que é brasa!

Considerando que *Brasil* vem de *brasa* ou *brasil*, faz sentido que ‘*Brésil*’ seja Brasil, como diz [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4746/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-brazil-brasil-in-modern-portuguese) em inglês.