# Qual a origem da palavra “manjericão” e por que é tão diferente?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Gostaria de saber qual a origem da palavra “manjericão” e por que ela difere tanto dos outros idiomas. Por exemplo:
Italiano: *basilico*
Francês: *basilic*
Inglês: *basil*
Alemão: *basilikum*
Norueguês: *basilikum*

Poderíamos atestar que tem origem ibérica/arábica. Mas no espanhol temos *albahaca*.

Qual a origem de um termo tão diferente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta curta é: não se sabe ao certo. O romanista Jules Cornu (1849-1919) sugeriu que *manjericão* é corruptela do grego *basilikón*. Esta hipótese vem mencionada no *Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa* de Antenor Nascentes, mas creio que não teve aceitação generalizada, pois os dicionários generalistas dizem simplesmente que a origem é obscura. Por outro lado, apesar de não ter visto isto defendido, parece-me plausível que *manjericão* tenha a mesma origem que *manjerona*, que sabemos vir do latim medieval *maiorana*. Quer *manjericão* quer *manjerona* já estavam presentes na língua em 1507.

Comecemos com o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002; desabrevio algumas abreviações):

> **manjericão** *s.m.* (1507 cf. VFern) **1** ANGIOSPÉRMICAS designação comum a várias plantas do género *Ocimum*, da família das labiadas […] ETIMOLOGIA origem obscura.; formas históricas 1507 *majericã*, antes de 1580 *mangericão*, 1611 *manjaricão*, 1858 *magericão*, 1939 *manjericão*

Os registos mais antigos de *manjericão* e *manjerona* são ambos do *Códice de Valentim Fernandes* de 1507 ([Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/); ênfase minha):

> Esta çidade Quyloa jaz em hûa ylha […] Aqui ha muytas laranjas doçes lymões rabõas e cebolinhas pequenas /**manjarona** e **majoricam** em seus quintaes que regam dos poços /

### A hipótese de Cornu—origem em *basilikón*

A passagem do grego *basilikón*, presumivelmente via latim medieval *basilicum*, para *manjericão*, parece surpreendente, mas o autor diz que o *b* passou igualmente a *m* em palavras como *barafunda/marafunda, barulhar/marulhar*, e *bisagra/misagra*[¹](https://archive.org/stream/grundissderroman01grbe#page/978/mode/2up) (segundo o Houaiss, termos antigos para ‘dobradiça’), e a passagem de *ma*- a *man* seria uma nasalização do *a* for efeito do *m* anterior, coisa que aconteceu também noutras palavras;[²](https://archive.org/stream/grundissderroman01grbe#page/984/mode/2up/) esta última passagem não é aliás problemática, uma vez que, como o Houaiss indica, estão registadas historicamente variantes com *ma-* e com *man-*.

O que não vi explicado foi a hipotética passagem do *-sili-* a *-jiri-*. Mas é verdade que o *-s-* intervocálico do português antigo soava vagamente intermédio entre *z* e *j*, como acontece ainda na fala de algumas pessoas no centro e norte de Portugal (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%C3%A7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%C3%BAncia-sinto-%E2%89%A0-cinto)); isto poderia ter facilitado a mudança. Por outro lado, o *l* do latim passou a *r* no português em muitas palavras, como *praça* (do latim *platea*) ou *cravo* (de *clavus*), mas não sei de *l* intervocálico, como em *basilicum*, que tenham passado a *r*.

### Origem comum de *manjericão* e *manjerona* em *maiorana*

Não encontrei ninguém a sugerir que *manjericão* e *manjerona* partilhem a mesma origem, mas parece-me que vale a pena considerar essa hipótese. A manjerona é uma planta da família do orégão, e não do manjericão, mas todas elas são ervas aromáticas com algumas semelhanças. E os nomes são tão parecidos que me parece estranho que a origem não seja comum ou que pelos menos uma palavra tenha influenciado a outra. E existe algum consenso que *manjerona*, tal como o espanhol [*mejorana* (RAE)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OnoXRGI), o italiano [*maggiorana* (Treccani)](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/maggiorana) e o francês antigo [*majorane* (CNRTL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/marjolaine) (o moderno é *marjolaine*), vêm do latim medieval *maiorana*.

Donde vem o latim medieval *maiorana* é que já é incerto. Houve quem sugerisse que vem do latim *amaracus*, que significa precisamente ‘manjerona’, mas a hipótese mais aceite é que é uma alteração influenciada por *maior* do latim tardio *mezurana* [(CNRTL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/marjolaine), que por sua terá provavelmente origem numa palavra do Próximo Oriente [(American Heritage)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Origanum+marjorana) ou da Índia [(Etymoline)].

Agora, isto é a origem de *manjerona*. Poderá ser também a origem de *manjericão* se estas palavras tiverem origem comum. Poderíamos também admitir que *manjericão* evoluiu de algum cruzamento de *basilicum* e *manjerona/maiorana*. Note-se que o latim medieval *maiorana* está atestado no século XIII, portanto suficientemente cedo para influenciar a palavra portuguesa *manjericão*

---

**Notas/Fontes:**
¹ [Jules Cornu, “Die portugiesiche Sprache,” in Gustav Grösser, *Grundriss der romanischen Philologie*, Strassburg, 1904-1906, p. 984, §170.](https://archive.org/stream/grundissderroman01grbe#page/978/mode/2up)
² [Idem, p. 979, §151.](https://archive.org/stream/grundissderroman01grbe#page/984/mode/2up/)

Comment: A origem a partir de manjerona parece lógica, mesmo sendo plantas de famílias diferentes, ambas são temperos e o manjericão é consideravelmente maior que a manjerona. Pode ter vindo de um sufixo com significado de “manjerona grande/maior”

Comment: @Stafusa, obrigado pela correção. Agora eu estava precisamente também a editar a resposta; aceitei a tua edição, e perdi a minha! Lol!

Comment: Ops! Desculpe por isso! :-)

Comment: @stafusa, Imagina! Foi culpa minha. Eu não sabia que ao aceitar a tua perdia a minha. Mas eu faço isto quase tudo no Word, não é assim tão difícil recuperar.

Comment: @Vitor, eu estou cada vez mais inclinado a aceitar origem comum. Um aumentativo direto de *manjerona* seria *manjeronão*, parece-me. Eu imaginei o seguinte. O *-ona* de *manjerona*, mesmo não sendo, é interpretado como o sufixo, e substituído por *-ico* (à laia de *bailarico, burrico*, etc.) para dar manjerico, que é uma planta mais pequena e delicada que a manjerona. E depois *manjericão* é aumentativo de *manjerico*. Problema: *manjericão* já existia em 1507, enquanto *manjerico* (e *manjarico, mangerico*, etc.) só encontro a partir do sXIX!

Comment: Minha família fala o dialeto vêneto do Italiano e eles pronunciam “basirico” para “basilico”. Achei um exemplo interessante da troca L intervocalico -> r.

Comment: @Vitor, é mesmo, logo na palavra que nos interessa. Quem sabe se os portugueses formaram o "manjerição" a partir do "basírico" veneziano? Lisboa na idade média era muito frequentada por mercadores italianos.

Answer (score 4):

A origem é desconhecida. Talvez um candidato possível seja o **sânscrito** ou outra língua indiana.

Os dicionários (e.g., [1](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/manjeric%C3%A3o/), [2](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/manjeric%C3%A3o), [3](https://www.dicio.com.br/manjericao/)) apontam a origem da palavra manjericão como sendo *desconhecida*, *obscura* e até *questionável*. Este parece ser o consenso.

Não encontrei menção a qual seria a tal origem "questionável", mas talvez seja relevante que:

- o manjericão (também *manjerico* e *marijona*) tem **majericã** como forma histórica mais antiga (1507) citada no Houaiss (cf. [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5270/2764) do Jacinto);
- a [palavra do sânscrito](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=maJjarIka&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3)  मञ्जरीक, transliterada como ***maJjarIka***, é o nome de uma espécie de manjericão, e transliterações listadas neste [site sobre ervas](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/engl/Ocim_bas.html?spicenames=pt) incluem *Mayangton* (ময়াংতোন) (em [manipuri](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_manipuri)) e *Manjari* (मञ्जरीक) (em sânscrito);
- e várias fontes (e.g., [esta](https://www.portalsaofrancisco.com.br/alimentos/manjericao), [esta](http://www.cloverleaffarmherbs.com/basil/) e a [Enciclopédia Britânica](https://www.britannica.com/plant/basil)) afirmam que a planta provavelmente chegou à Europa vinda da Índia, há cerca de 4 mil anos.

Esses fatos talvez sugiram o sânscrito ou uma língua relacionada como candidato à origem da palavra manjericão. Em particular, o *Mayangton* (ময়াংতোন) (da região de [Manipur](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manipur)) [é descrito](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/engl/Ocim_bas.html?spicenames=pt) como uma variedade asiática mais similar à mediterrânea. É importante não omitir, no entanto, que o principal termo para manjericão em sânscrito é [tulasI](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=basil&direct=es&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) (तुलसी), que não guarda semelhança alguma com o português.

O curto intervalo de tempo entre o início do comércio com "as Índias" e o primeiro uso registrado da palavra torna improvável, como o Jacinto comenta, uma origem indiana direta - e uma língua intermediária, por exemplo o latim, poderia ser necessária. A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5270/2764) do Jacinto faz uma sugestão muito interessante nesse sentido (a saber, "uma alteração influenciada por *maior* do latim tardio *mezurana*, que por sua terá provavelmente origem numa palavra do Oriente Próximo ou da Índia").

Vale também notar que no português também temos o sinônimo "alfavaca", de mesma origem árabe ( الحبق - [al-habaqa](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/alfavaca)) que o espanhol *albahaca* e outros nomes ibéricos.

Comment: Eu encontrei dicionários etimológicos a propor origens asiáticas, mas via latim, para *manjerona*; o que não está esclarecido, claro, é se *manjericão* tem a mesma origem. Agora, na tua resposta não está claro é se tu propões que o sânscrito ou outra língua indiana seja a origem direta de *manjericão* (os portugueses foram lá, ouviram e adaptaram) ou se foi via outras línguas (árabe ou grego + latim, por exemplo). Neste último caso deveriam existir formas parecidas também nessas línguas intermédias. Para transmissão direta, parece-me que não houve tempo suficiente.

Comment: É um ótimo ponto. A via árabe me parece improvável, já que o nome antigo (e também o atual) é bastante diferente. Confesso que eu considerava a via direta a mais provável mas, agora que você me chamou a atenção para o curto intervalo de tempo entre o início do comércio com "as Índias" e o primeiro uso registrado da palavra, concordo que deve mesmo ter havido algum intermediário. A via pelo latim talvez seja a mais provável, mas não tenho recursos (ou conhecimento) para investigar.